# Function added to window.location not being found

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add the following function to `window.location` when the javascript file loads.

```
if (!window.location.queryString) {
    window.location.queryString = function(url) {
        // return array of query string variables
    }
}
```

The code that calls this function is in a jQuery doc ready function.
If it gets called too soon after the page loads, it returns `TypeError: window.location.queryString is not a function`

This code appears before the function that calls it in the same bundled file.

Why is this acting like a timing issue?

Comment: Well if the code defined before you call it?

Comment: @epascarello the code I posted above is in the javascript file above the the code that calls it.

Comment: And is the function inside some other method that gets triggered later?

Comment: Why are you adding a function to `window.location`, especially one that accepts an arbitrary url as a parameter?

Comment: @epascarello Nope. It appears in the file like it does above.

Comment: @JoeEnos It's optional.  If you don't pass it a url it uses window.location.href.

Comment: Without a [mcve] all we can do is guess

Comment: It's generally considered bad practice to extend built-in types, especially those in the BOM (browser object model) and DOM. See [this Software Engineering question](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/104320/222246) for more information on why.